# ArchUnit base type thrown wrong

Tags: archunit

[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   DomainLayerTest$all.domain_layer_depend_on_rule:29 Architecture Violation [Priority: MEDIUM] - Rule 'The domain layer should only depend on the classes in the package of java and domain.' was violated (1 times):
Field <com.abc.test.domain.contexts.configcontext.config.LdapBasicSetting.SECRET_KEY> has type <[B> in (LdapBasicSetting.java:0)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixv49.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbSfG.png)

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of screenshots. And maybe you can also find a more descriptive title? Thanks!

Comment: OK, I'll get it next time

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part of your rule is not shown in your screenshot, but I assume that your

```java
.should().onlyDependOnClassesThat().resideInAnyPackage( /*allowed packages*/ )
```

statement does not include the empty package `""`, which is the package of the type  `byte[]`.